# Picolisp question, segfault when manipulating lists of numbers (from mailing list)

Tags: lisp, picolisp

I'm new to Picolisp.

I tried this, and obtained a segfault:

```
: ('(1 2) 6)
Segmentation fault
```

But, if i try:

```
: ('(a b c) 6)
-> NIL
```

I mostly understand why, but it was a surprise that PicoLisp responded with a segfault instead of an error. Does this means that Picolisp doesn't check if a number is a function but it does when it is a symbol?

Comment: (Question lifted from the picolisp mailing list.)

Comment: Yes, it should not segfault. It should check for that, and provide an informative error message without quitting the REPL.

Comment: PicoLisp takes a more hardcore approach and is a language closer to the actual machine (CPU) than most interpreted languages. So this behavior is not considered a bug. Just as you can crash a process in C you can in PicoLisp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Lifted from [picolisp mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/picolisp@software-lab.de/msg01237.html).)

Yes, this is the expected behavior.

PicoLisp evaluates the CAR of a list, perhaps repeatedly, until it hits
upon a function. A function is either a list (then it is a Lisp-level
function) or a short number (then it is a built-in function, written in
either asm or C). If that number does not point to executable code
(which is difficult to check at runtime), a crash happens.

I would consider such a crash an "extended error message": Why not let
the hardware (MMU) do the runtime check?

In general, it is not possible to have the interpreter catch any
possible error (think of infinite loops, for example), so PicoLisp takes
the stand of giving some responsibility to the programmer.

In practice, an error like the above one will be detected at the first
test run of your program.

BTW, an exception to the above rule is only a list that directly has a
number in its CAR. Such a list auto-evaluates:

```
   : (1 2 3)
   -> (1 2 3)
```

Is just a convenient feature, not having to quote such constant lists.

```
: ('(a b c) 6)
-> NIL
```

> I mostly understand why, but it was a
>   surprise that Picolisp responded with
>   a segfault instead of an error. Does
>   this means that Picolisp doesn't check
>   if a number is a function but it does
>   when it is a symbol?

In that case, (a b c) is in fact a legal function definition: It is a
function with a single symbolic parameter 'a' (so that function does not
evaluate its arguments), and a body of two symbols. This is equivalent
to

```
   : (de foo a
      b
      c )
   -> foo
```

When this function is executed, it binds the argument list (3) to that
symbol 'a', then executes 'b' and 'c'. This function returns the value
of 'c', which was NIL in your example.

> When you do:
>
> ```
> : (de foo H H) 
>
> : (foo 1 2 3)
> -> (1 2 3) 
>
> : foo
> -> (H H)
> ```
>
> so you can also do:
>
> ```
> : ('(H H) 1 2 3)
> -> (1 2 3)
> ```

Correct.

> I bet you know what happens here; you
>   are trying to use a number as a
>   variable, which is illegal -> crash
>   (besides it does not make sense
>   anyway)

It is correct what you said. The interpreter hits upon '1' in the place
of an expected function parameter.

```
   : (setq 7 5)  
   !? (setq 7 5)
   7 -- Variable expected
   ?
```